# Fronting Tomcat with Apache HTTP Server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

***Apache Tomcat server.xml:***

```
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" address="127.0.0.1" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

***Apache Http Server httpd.conf :***

> cd /path/to/apache/config

```
LoadModule proxy_module       modules/mod_proxy.so       
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module   modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass       / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ retry=0
```

When i do http://[ip]/[app_name] i have this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /[app_name] on this server.

Why ?

Comment: `Deny from all` / `Allow from localhost` ? Unless you're using either `127.0.0.1` or `::1` as `[ip]`

Comment: @OlafKock as [ip] i use this http://172.12.6.3/Myapp

Comment: Then I'll transfer this comment to be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration states

```
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
```

Guess the meaning of `Deny` and `Allow`. Your configuration should work if you are coming from the same server and use `localhost` as your address. Careful if you use the IP address: Often `localhost` is no longer mapped to `127.0.0.1`, but to `::1`, its IPV6 equivalent.

Edit: Remove this block and try if it works then.

Note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions, this is rather server administration, so it might be better on https://serverfault.com/ - I'm voting to transfer it over to that site. There people might be able to go further - e.g. give hints to not open up a reverse proxy for everybody everywhere on the internet.

Comment: so What changes should I do ?

Comment: edited and voted to transfer this question to serverfault.com